# How can I get the differences of all elements of list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to get the difference of all elements of a list for example:

$L=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ for any $i$ and $j$ $\in L$ return the differences,
for example for the first element $1$ we get the difference with the rest of elements $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$  we can use the `Abs` to get  the absolute value of the differnce.

I used `Differences` but this gives the successive differences of elements in list.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
L = Range[6]
Outer[#1-#2&, L, L]
```

Comment: Maybe easier to read: `Outer[Subtract,L,L]`

Comment: `DistanceMatrix[]` is better for this.

Comment: @J.M. correct and more concise certainly.  But better?  I'd prefer a design pattern that I can reuse in any number of ways over a relatively obscure function that is only in the latest versions of Mathematica.

Comment: @mikado. Depends on what you want. If `DistanceMatrix[]` is optimized for this particular calculation, then it's worth using for large lists in certain applications. There's a difference between solving a particular problem and learning general coding practice, and some people don't need the latter.

Comment: @J.M. I hadn't thought of `DistanceMatrix` - I guess it's too new (only introduced last year)... now that I looked for it it seems that this is a duplicate.